# Getting Android Device Identifier From ADB and Android SDK

Tags: android, adb

I am looking for the easiest way to get a unique android device identifier from both the Android adb and the Android ADK itself.

For example, when i use the adb 'devices' command, the serial number of my connected device is outputted to the screen.  I have yet to identify a method in the Android sdk to get me the same serial number.

I don't care what unique identifier is used, just something that can be easily retrieved from both the adb and android sdk.  Rooting a device will not be an option.

Comment: Could you track installations instead of devices?

Comment: found look into following answer. 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/23564966/884052

Answer (score 74):

You would probably want to use ANDROID_ID.

This is how you can query its value via adb shell:

```
settings get secure android_id
```

Or by querying the settings content provider:

```
content query --uri content://settings/secure/android_id --projection value
```

Comment: Content doesn't seem to be a found by the shell?

Comment: Just escape the ['] chars in the end of the query to run it smoothly.

Comment: or as a single oneliner: `adb shell 'settings get secure android_id'`

Answer (score 18):

Simple as that with **adb**

```
adb devices -l
```

Answer (score 13):

Android stores all the device related info in one or the other sqlite DB.
These databases can be found in /data/data/ folder.
To read these databases from adb you will need root permissions.

The android id is available in /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db

So for adb use this command.

```
adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "select value from secure where name = 'android_id'"
```

**you must be running adb as root in adb

Comment: Author has mentioned that rooting a device is not an option

Answer (score 8):

The Android serial number can be retreived within the device with [getprop](http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-shell-getprop) :

`getprop ro.serialno`

From Java, you may want to execute it with [Runtime.exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28158297/1192811)

Comment: serial number is **not** the same as android id.

Comment: @ccpizza exact, but OP wanted **any** device id

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. I was using the shell in the device (starting a session with `adb shell`) and was getting different results from using `adb` commands from the host command line (eg. `adb shell pm list packages`).  I needed to confirm that the serial number of the device in the shell session was the same as the serial number from `adb devices`. It was, so I had to look elsewhere for why my commands weren't working.

Answer (score 6):

Try [ANDROID_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID). As documentation says "[it] is randomly generated on first boot and should remain constant for the lifetime of the device".

Comment: Do have any idea of how this can be accessed from adb?

Comment: As far as I know most reliable way will be to create an application that copies it (ANDORID_ID) to database. Than you can access this database trough adb (use [sqlite3](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite) command from shell).

Comment: I haven't tested it myself but you may also find ANDORID_ID already stored in this places:
- /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db - table secure
- /data/data/com.google.android.googleapps/databases/gls.db - table meta

Answer (score 6):

I use adb. First I list the attached device ID numbers with the following command:

```
adb devices
```

And the output will look something like this:

```
List of devices attached
YOGAA1BBB412    device
```

From the previous output, you will need the device ID number (eg: `YOGAA1BBB412`). To get the Device ID, I use the following adb command:

```
adb -s YOGAA1BBB412 shell getprop | grep product.model
```

And the output looks like this:

```
[ro.product.model]: [Lenovo YT3-X90F]
```

Comment: You'd think that `adb devices` would show that by default. Thanks for this.

Comment: Ah, it does. You just need to use the `-l` flag for long output.

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure your device is connected by running the below command.

```
adb devices -l
```

after that to get the android id of that device you can run the below command.

```
adb shell content query --uri content://settings/secure --where "name=\'android_id\'"
```

Answer (score 1):

*adb shell settings get secure android_id*

This command returns ANDROID_ID but it may not be the same as ANDROID_ID received at code level. The application can use different min API level and the value obtained from adb shell may not match

It was possible to get the ANDROID_ID from [net.hostname] prop. It worked in API level 23.

Command to get the android_id for API level 23

*adb shell getprop net.hostname*

In android 8.0 and above this prop returns null due to android privacy policy changes.
Hence, ANDROID_ID doesn't remain to be a reliable method of unique device id comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and find the `id` besides Android. The command gives basically all info about the phone.

```
adb -s <YOUR-DEVICE-ID> shell getprop
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getprop net.hostname` which has an [Android unique Id](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID) followed by keyword `android-<64 bit Hexadecimal String>`

example:

```
[net.hostname]: [android-a487e0560d669e4a]
```

Answer (score -1):

To find everything about connected usb device on ubuntu  use below command
lsusb -v
See the link
[image]
it will give u device id like
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 18d1:4ee7 Google Inc.
So use first four "18d1" to add android usb rules

Answer (score -3):

you should probably use IMEI:

```
    TelephonyManager m = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String imei = m != null ? m.getDeviceId() : null;
```

Comment: IMEI may not be a good proxy for a unique identifier since you can't guarantee that every device your app runs on will have a cell radio. Given that you can specify a <uses-feature> for android.hardware.telephony, I wouldn't recommend assuming the presence of telephony hardware. On the other hand, if you're happy restricting your app to only those devices with telephony hardware, then this should be useable.