# How to get ro.build.version.security_patch value on Android Kitkat(API19) and below

Tags: android, security, patch, android-4.4-kitkat

Well when I execute

```
   adb shell getprop ro.build.version.security_patch
```

It gives me the [security patch level property](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SECURITY_PATCH) on android >= Lollipop only, So my question is how to get the current patch level on older android devices.

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42977813/6950238) answer.

Comment: Already checked it doesn't help :|

Comment: It doesn't exist so you can't get it. AFAIK, security patches were introduced in Lollipop to patch bugs without having to overhaul the entire system and incrementing the Android version. So you can't access it because it doesn't exist

Comment: whats the use case ?

Comment: @Zoe Thank you for your answer I will check the value of "ro.build.version.incremental" property on older android versions

Comment: @Akhil I want to know which security patch is currently installed on the device.