# Bottom view cutout for rounded bottom screen corners [Display Cutout]

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

**When there is a full screen enabled from the device display setting and the phone has a rounded edge on the bottom then my buttons at the bottom cut out a little bit. I have found some reference for notch cutout but not able to find the bottom cutout.**

Solution Assumption: Margin at bottom >> Not fulfill my XD requirement. My buttons should be at the bottom without margin.

*Please refer below screenshot.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cutout mode either programmatically or by setting a style in your activity. The example below defines a [style](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes) that you can use to apply the `LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES` attribute to the activity

```
<style name="ActivityTheme">
  <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">
    shortEdges <!-- default, shortEdges, never -->
  </item>
</style>
```

For more detail [Click Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout/#choose_how_your_app_handles_cutout_areas)

Comment: It requires minimum API level 27.

Comment: this type of device available on API level 27 and above

Comment: Not worked for me.
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/App_EditTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode" tools:targetApi="o_mr1">
            shortEdges <!-- default, shortEdges, never -->
        </item>
    </style>

Comment: Check Display Cutout for different devices https://stackoverflow.com/a/56609043/9523118

Comment: yeah great! But that's all about notch display. I mean top. No reference for the bottom.