# How to get RoundedCorners to work with latest Android

Tags: android, rounded-corners

My phone (a Samsung Galaxy S21) has rounded corners on its display screen. I want to add padding to my View so that some text doesn't get cut off by the rounded corners. I was using this code, which worked and did return a nonzero value:-

```
    private int getCornerAllowance() {
        // return 0 if this Android version doesn't do rounded corners
        int i = 0;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            Display disp = getDisplay();
            // the corner radii are normally all the same
            // but we find the largert one just in case
            RoundedCorner rc = disp.getRoundedCorner(
                RoundedCorner.POSITION_BOTTOM_LEFT);
            int j = rc.getRadius();
            if (j > i) { i = j; }
            rc = disp.getRoundedCorner(
                RoundedCorner.POSITION_BOTTOM_RIGHT);
            j = rc.getRadius();
            if (j > i) { i = j; }
            rc = disp.getRoundedCorner(
                RoundedCorner.POSITION_TOP_LEFT);
            j = rc.getRadius();
            if (j > i) { i = j; }
            rc = disp.getRoundedCorner(
                RoundedCorner.POSITION_TOP_RIGHT);
            j = rc.getRadius();
            if (j > i) { i = j; }
        }
        return i;
    }
```

and I called it like this

```
        mResults = new ListView(this);
        int p = getCornerAllowance() * 3 / 10;
        mResults.setPadding(p, 0, p, p);
```

but after a recent android operating system upgrade, it crashes because `getRoundedCorner` now returns null.

In case the `RoundedCorner` objects were no longer getting initialised until the view got attached to a window, I tried this instead

`... implementsView.OnAttachStateChangeListener ...`

```
    private int getCornerAllowance() {
        // return 0 if this Android version doesn't do rounded corners
        int i = 0;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            WindowInsets insets = m_container.getRootWindowInsets();
            if (insets != null) {
                // the corner radii are normally all the same
                // but we find the largest one just in case
                RoundedCorner rc = insets.getRoundedCorner(
                        RoundedCorner.POSITION_BOTTOM_LEFT);
                if (rc != null) {
                    int j = rc.getRadius();
                    if (j > i) {
                        i = j;
                    }
                }
                rc = insets.getRoundedCorner(
                        RoundedCorner.POSITION_BOTTOM_RIGHT);
                if (rc != null) {
                    int j = rc.getRadius();
                    if (j > i) {
                        i = j;
                    }
                }
                rc = insets.getRoundedCorner(
                        RoundedCorner.POSITION_TOP_LEFT);
                if (rc != null) {
                    int j = rc.getRadius();
                    if (j > i) {
                        i = j;
                    }
                }
                rc = insets.getRoundedCorner(
                        RoundedCorner.POSITION_TOP_RIGHT);
                if (rc != null) {
                    int j = rc.getRadius();
                    if (j > i) {
                        i = j;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
```

```
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull View view) {
        int p = getCornerAllowance() * 3 / 10;
        mResults.setPadding(p,0,p,p);
    }
```

but all the `RoundedCorner` objects are still null. What am I doing wrong here? Does anyone have code to get rounded corner radius on current versions of Android?

The full code is available [here](https://github.com/rparkins999/xword).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51743622/how-to-handle-notchdisplay-cutout-in-android-api-lower-than-28/56609043#56609043

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51743622/how-to-handle-notchdisplay-cutout-in-android-api-lower-than-28/56609043#56609043 check these I hope you find your solution

Comment: I tried overriding `OnDraw` and looking at the window insets after the view has been drawn on the screen. The `RoundedCorner`s are still all uninitialised.

Comment: do you get any errors?. tbh it's weird that such thing isn't handled by the OS

Comment: The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51743622/how-to-handle-notchdisplay-cutout-in-android-api-lower-than-28/56609043#56609043 isn't relevant. Rounded corners are quite different from the notch display cutout. As I said, I do get an error if I try to dereference the objects returned by `getRoundedCorner`, because they are null.

Comment: gotcha. update your question with the error message

Comment: As my original question says, `getRoundedCorner` always returns null. If I don't check for null the app crashes when I dereference the returned `RoundedCorner`. There is no error message. Error messages are produced by the build system or by apps, not by the Android runtime (apart from "app keeps crashing").

Comment: According to https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/insets/rounded-corners, I can use `rootWindowInsets.getRoundedCorner` to get the radius and center point for rounded corners of the device screen. I can find no way of getting a non-null result, and my device does have rounded corners on its display, and the app's root window does include a rounded corner of the display, and its UI does get truncated because `rootWindowInsets.getRoundedCorner` returns null.

Comment: I honestly don't know where to go from this. ill be following your question and waiting for an answer.