# Unique identifier (when targeting Android 10, lasting after factory reset)

Tags: android, android-10.0

I have this internal android app for the phones. 
The company has it's own custom management for all the devices.
Hole thing is working based on the **imei** , as a unique key to identify each phone.

As you know from Android 10, the imei identifier is not accessible anymore.
I have read a bunch of post and articles, but none seems to satisfy my needs, as I need an **unique identifier**, that lasts also after factory ***reset, reboot, uninstall*** and so on.

Please any suggestions, are welcomed.

Comment: Already covered by [Android 10: IMEI no longer available on API 29. Looking for alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58103580/295004) If you find a loophole, it will probably be closed.

Comment: I have read the post, no identifier from the proposed ones, lasts after factory reset :(

Comment: All I can suggest is to modify your custom management to reflect the change in Android or see if your phone manufacturer has a proprietary solution.

Comment: I was hopping for an easier solution... what about taking  an unique identifier through adb?

Comment: I think this is sort of what you are asking: [Getting Android Device Identifier From ADB and Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5486694/295004) but from Android 8.0 changes after factory reset. Or [Android: How to programmatically access the device serial number shown in the AVD manager (API Version 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11029294/295004)

Answer (score 0):

Check first Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58103580/android-10-imei-no-longer-available-on-api-29-looking-for-alternatives/59050182#59050182).

it's using UUID with MediaDrm.

**Tested** on Xiaomi Pocophone F1 with Android 10
and it survived **reboot, uninstall**.

I didn't test it yet over the factory reset.

Comment: As per my test it does not survive factory reset.