# How can I get android id using ADB and within Unity application?

Tags: unity-game-engine, adb, virtual-reality

I need to get the AndroidID using ADB and inside the unity application check if it's the same device using the AndroidID.

With this command, using ADB I have the AndroidID:

```
adb shell settings get secure android_id
>> a9822db857e4****
```

And inside the unity application, I'm using this code:

```
AndroidJavaClass clsUnity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject objActivity = clsUnity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
AndroidJavaObject objResolver = objActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getContentResolver");
AndroidJavaClass clsSecure = new AndroidJavaClass("android.provider.Settings$Secure");
string android_id = clsSecure.CallStatic<string>("getString", objResolver, "android_id");
>> android_id = 98ff3a034b16****
```

You may notice that the IDs are different.
Does anyone have a solution for this?
How can I get that same identifier using ADB and in unity ?

Answer (score 0):

If your device runs Android version > Android 8.0 (API level 26), the ANDROID_ID string [is unique to each app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64572476) (more precisely, to each app-signing key - so more like unique to all your apps you signed with the same key). You can check out all the changes related to ANDROID_ID [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#privacy-all).

If you are running Android version < 8.0, you might have multiple users and they will have separate ids - maybe you are getting root users' id via ADB and the whatever-user-launched-your-app id from code? (See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID)).